# self.cleaned_data.get returns none even if field was declared

Tags: django

When i'm in the admin page and trying to create a new instance of `MyUser` I am unable to create it. When I print out `password` and `confirm_password`, I get the proper value for `password` but `None` for `confirm_password`.

In my `admins.py` file, I have the following:

```
class MyUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form for creating new users.
    """
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(
        label='Confirm password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        models = MyUser
        fields = ('email', )

    def clean_password(self):
        """
        Check if two password entries match.
        """
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')
        if (password == confirm_password):
            return password
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")

    def save(self):
        """
        Save the provided password in hash format.
        """
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

---

What could be causing as to why `confirm_password` always have the value `None`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do this code in the clean_password.

It makes more sense to do it inside clean_confirm_password
Here is a snipet retrieve from django source code:

```
def clean_confirm_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")
        if password and confirm_password and password != confirm_password:
            #you can keep your simply Validation Error here
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
    return password2
```

And for the save try:

```
 def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

Otherwise your code seems to be good.
So maybe the error is somewhere else.

Here for your information: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L70